# Error looping over ShellWindows

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, hresult, shdocvw

I occasionally get the "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component." error when looping over the ShellWindows class.  Seems to happen mostly after the computer wakes from sleeping.  I have to restart my computer to clear this error which is not good.

The error happens on the "foreach" loop line in the following code:

```
log.Debug(String.Format("new ShellWindowsClass"));
ShellWindows m_IEFoundBrowsers = new ShellWindowsClass();

log.Debug(String.Format("Loop begin"));
foreach (InternetExplorer Browser in m_IEFoundBrowsers)
{
    log.Debug(String.Format("Browser {0} ?= {1}", Browser.HWND, pid));
    if (Browser.HWND == pid)
    {
        found = Browser;
        break;
    }
}
log.Debug(String.Format("Loop end"));
```

I am compiling for Dot Net Framework 3.0.

Any suggestions for addressing this error besides restart the computer?

Comment: This happens after the computer is fully awake.

Comment: I deleted my answer. I don't know much on this. I thought the link http://weblogs.asp.net/joberg/articles/405283.aspx might help based on the guess it's COM component is in some intermediate state and call to it fails. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 2):

From  [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sk/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/dbdc3707-16cf-44ad-a681-fe92eb9bc853) I found the solution.  The problem is not in the start of the loop, but instead in the first debug logging statement.  This line of code is what's failing.

```
log.Debug(String.Format("Browser {0} ?= {1}", Browser.HWND, pid));
```

and it is failing because `Browser.HWND` is what is throwing the exception.

The solution is to examine the `Browser` variable and check its process name.  Get the process name like this:

```
string processName 
  = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Browser.FullName).ToLower();
```

Doing this, I typically saw the value for `processName` to be either:

1. `"iexplore"`
2. `"explorer"`

When `processName="explorer"`, the call to `Browser.HWND` causes the  "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component." error.

To prevent the error, add an if statement:

```
if (processName.Equals("iexplore")) { . . . }
```

And only act if this if statement is true.